# Is flyway database agnostic in its support for multiple databases?

Tags: flyway

Is [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) suitable for implementation in an application that will support multiple databases?

We don't know what our customers are using - could be either MySQL, Postgres or Oracle. Can we still use Flyway to migrate the database for new versions of the application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if your question is: does **Flyway** provide a **DDL abstraction layer** across the databases it supports, the answer is **no**.

This was a conscious design decision, to make sure the **full power of the underlying database** is available and not just the smallest common denominator supported by the migration tool.

For your use case, you could either provide different migration scripts for the different databases. They should be very similar though.

If you do not wish to potentially duplicate the migration scripts and can live with the **smallest common denominator** approach, have a look at **[LiquiBase](http://www.liquibase.org/)** which might be a better fit for your usecase (if you can live with the XML)

Comment: Axel, If the same migration script is provided for different databases, how can the selection of the database to use be done? Is sth like V1__ORACLE_InitalVersion.sql and V1__MSSQL_InitialVersion.sql  possible?

Comment: One possibility might be to configure flyway.baseDir depending on your environment with one directory for SQL Server migrations and one for the Oracle ones.

Comment: Is it possible to have separate scripts for only those things that are different? If the first three versions are standard sql, but for the forth version you need a special script for, let's say SQL Server, can you then keep the common scripts?

Comment: @homaxto Yes, you can. You can have one directory for the common  scripts and then for each database a separate directory for the specific scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jOOQ's parsing connection](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/parsing-connection/), which wraps your target JDBC connection and is capable of translating your input DDL to any target dialect (if it's not too fancy and vendor specific). Flyway wouldn't be aware of this translating JDBC proxy, and wouldn't have to be. The online version of the [SQL translator](https://www.jooq.org/translate/) can be seen here. For example, if your input SQL is a MySQL specific:

```sql
create table t (i int primary key auto_increment);
```

The output could be:

```sql
-- Oracle
create table T (
  I number(10) generated by default as identity(start with 1) not null,
  primary key (I)
);

-- SQL Server
create table T (
  I int identity(1, 1) not null,
  primary key (I)
)

-- PostgreSQL
create table T (
  I int generated by default as identity not null,
  primary key (I)
)

-- PostgreSQL 9.4
create table T (
  I serial4 not null,
  primary key (I)
)
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.

Comment: HI @Lukas Eder, the JOOQ Sql-Translator online web app, it says on your site, "Cool, can I embed this in my application!?
Yes! And you don't even need to use the jOOQ API. The parser can be exposed through the JDBC API.",

Comment: I want to embed this into a simple java console type app, so  I can pass in say Sqlite sql-script and then  as output get MySQL script. I tried the online you have think it is very good. Hope you can guide me to how to do this. Hope there is documentation.

Comment: @Palu: Did you check out the link to the [`ParsingConnection`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/parsing-connection/) from my answer?